# spark error "It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast "

Tags: broadcast, pyspark

Here are the functions in my class:

```
def labeling(self, value, labelMap, dtype='string'):
        if dtype.value == 'string':
            result = [i for v,i in labelMap.value if value==v][0]
            return result
        else:
            result = [i for v,i in labelMap.value if value<v][0]
            return result

def labelByValue(self, labelMap, dtype='string'):
        labeling = self.labeling
        labelMap = self.sc.broadcast(labelMap)
        dtype = self.sc.broadcast(dtype)
        self.RDD = self.RDD.map(labeling)
```

but when I call the function below in "**main**", it report error like:""It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast ""

```
class.RDD.labelByValue((('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)))
```

I could not find anything by myself. 
So I came here for a help 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I finally finished this error.

The wrong point is that the user defined function should be put in global environment, not in the class.

So the labeling should be like this:

```
def labeling(value, labelMap, dtype='string'):
        if dtype.value == 'string':
            result = [i for v,i in labelMap.value if value==v][0]
            return result
        else:
            result = [i for v,i in labelMap.value if value<v][0]
            return result
```

Comment: Got  a similar issue and moved the UDF outside of the class. It works!

Comment: Met a similar problem when deal with Dstream. Solved by making the function global. Thanks for your post.